# How do I redirect a user to the menu with a button in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple app where someone is first shown an opening screen. There is a button, which, upon clicking, redirects you to menu.xml. But it says that it cannot resolve the symbol menu.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView text0 = findViewById(R.id.pozdrav);
        text0.setText("Greetings");
    }

    public void clickingToGo(View view) {
        Intent letsGo= new Intent(getBaseContext(), menu.class);
        startActivity(letsGo);
    }
}
```

I tried putting the menu in manifest directly, as I thought this may resolve the issue, but it changed nothing.

Comment: If you want to start a new `Activity` called `menu`, then you need to have a class that is called `menu` that `extends AppCompatActivity` and you need to have this in your manifest in an `<activity>` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

do use Button must use method `ButtonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`
and the Intent take toy to Activity Class ,
menu it is Activity Class ????
can you show the Code or show all the project , hier or in GitHub please